# Accordion not working when it is loaded within jquery $.post

Tags: php, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am stuck in working with dynamic accordion for the jQuery POST content.

In the firtpage.php, I have accordion `div` with dynamic table contents.

**firstpage.php**

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>section 1</h3>
  <div>
     <table>
     //dynamic table using php scripts
     </table>
  </div>
  <h3>section 2</h3>
  <div>
     <table>
     //dynamic table using php scripts
     </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the second page, I have loaded the firstpage.php using jQuery `$.post` method and on success, I set the according function.

**secondpage.php**

```
<p id="click">reload</p>
<div id="result"></div>

$('#click').click(function() {

    $.post('firtpage.php, function(data) {
    $('#result').html(data);
        $("#accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    heightStyle: "content"
    });
});
});
```

On first time, when I click `p` tag, accordion working fine.  When I click second time, accordion not working.

Here, what I need to achieve, every time the post load the firstpage, the sections should be accordion.

Comment: You want the #accordion section to reload on the second press of <p>?

Comment: yes,...I always needed the firtpage.php contents are displayed as according in secondpage.php.  but, the problem is , when I click first time it is working.  second time, it is not accordion.

Comment: You'd really be better off generating data you need in the table with one of the pages, then building the UI (yes, tables and all) in the page you're going to view.  Also, buttons are more semantically correct for triggers as opposed to your click paragraph.

Comment: Hang on, I'm having success with this... I'll post an answer soon

Answer (score 0):

You should populate your `accordion()` again. Please try this solution.

```
$('#click').click(function() {
    $.post('report.php', function(data) {

        // Destroy your old accordion
        $("#accordion").accordion("destroy");

        $('#result').html(adata);
        $("#accordion").accordion({
             collapsible: true,
             active: false,
             heightStyle: "content"
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: [http://jsbin.com/tokuda/2/](http://jsbin.com/tokuda/2/edit?js,output)

Comment: Were you able to get your accordion to reload properly now?